# uninitialized constant Neo4j::Session (NameError)

Tags: ruby, neo4j, rubygems

Reading the instructions contained in the address https://neo4j.com/developer/ruby/ I built the following code:

```
require 'neo4j'

session = Neo4j::Session.open(
    :server_db,
    "http://neo4j:password@localhost:7687"
)
```

I have this error:

```
uninitialized constant Neo4j::Session (NameError).
```

I don't understand if it is necessary to instantiate `Neo4j` or if it is necessary to redefine `Session`. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Have you added the gem and run `bundle` afterwards ?

Comment: @Viktor sure, but the problem persists